# TWRP can not find partitions

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, twrp, partitions

I had installed CWM recovery and used it to restore previous rom once and now I installed TWRP recovery (and I hope it replaced CWM because I used Odin3 to install both of them). Now I need to create backup of my device before wiping; But there is no partition detected in TWRP to backup:

Here is what shown on my device when I goto backup page and the errors shown after trying to backup:

[image: backup page] [image: errors]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The error was because my partitions were marked to be read only and TWRP version 2.7.0.0 was not checking that!

I installed TWRP version 3.0.0 and before starting new version it asked me a confirmation to make partitions editable and this simple step solved the problem.